# populating data from text file to char array in java

Tags: java, arrays, char, file-handling

i am creating a function to read a maze from file file contains size of an maze **[row] , [col] , [Entrypoint_row], [EntryPoint_Col] , [ExitPoint_row] , [ExitPoint_Col]** and then maze data

- currently file have data like
  1[image]

  public  void readMaze() throws FileNotFoundException
  {

/used to store entry points and exit points

```
    int EntryPoints[]=new int[2];
    int ExitPoints[]=new int[2];

    try
    {
        String line="";
        FileReader fr=new FileReader("maze.txt");
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
```

- reading data into *line* as string
- split the string variable *line* to an char array *arr*
- get data from arr to declared variables

  ```
      line=br.readLine();
      String arr[]=line.split(" ");
      row=Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
      col=Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);

      this.AllocateMaze(row, col);  //allocating size of maze row and col from file
      EntryPoints[0]=Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
      EntryPoints[1]=Integer.parseInt(arr[3]);
      ExitPoints[0]=Integer.parseInt(arr[4]);
      ExitPoints[1]=Integer.parseInt(arr[5]);
      System.out.println("row :"+row+"col :"+col);
      System.out.println("exit points  :"+EntryPoints[0]+" : "+EntryPoints[1]);
      System.out.println("exit points  :"+ExitPoints[0]+" : "+ExitPoints[1]);

      int i=0,k=0;
      boolean flag=true;
  ```
- populating maze[][] with data in file char by char

  ```
      while(!(line=br.readLine()).equals(null))
      {
          k=0;
          for(int j=0;j<row;j++)
          {
  ```

  **Here i got array outof bound exception at i=8,j=8 why is that i cannot find the way to handle it need help**

  ```
              maze[i][j]=String.valueOf(line.charAt(k));//here
              k++;
          }
          i++;

      }

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1):

Have you added some space on your exit point ?
From what I can understand, the ArrayOutOfBound exception is more likely thrown by the  line.charAt(k), in which case, 'k' is around 9, and the line is like 9 characters long, so you get this exception.
You probably need the line to be exactly 10 characters, so, you should add spaces or a specific characters like 'x'.

Comment: yes that was the mistake but still i got null pointer excepton at **while(!(line=br.readLine()).equals(null))**  is there any problem in this line?

Comment: Yes, there is a problem. You cannot compare a null value with 'equals', because your value is null, so, you get an NPE.
Just use while(!((line=br.readLine()) == null))

Comment: this worked **while((line=br.readLine())!=null)** thanks alot **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Where do you initiate `maze[][]`?
The columns and rows are 10, read from the file, so is this as well the size of your array? 
Because if it throws the exception at 8 like you say, it seems 2 short.

Comment: its the method in **mazeGame** class all these attributes are in class and succesfully initiallizes i check that by printing **row col** and its **10,10**

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while(!(line=br.readLine()).equals(null))
```

to

```
while((line=br.readLine()) != null)
```

and

```
for(int j=0;j<row;j++)
```

to

```
for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
```